# Why does a LinearLayout which is invisible take up space?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got the following LinearLayout...

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout3" android:visibility="invisible" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/S"></TextView>
<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/b"></TextView>
<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/Ar"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I've set the visibly to invisible but the LinearLayout still takes up space causing padding between two other linearlayouts in the layout, why? How do I make it take up no space?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Because you have to set the visibility to `gone` if you want that the view takes no space.

Answer (score 13):

The documentation of [`Invisible`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE) says:

> This view is invisible, but it still
>   takes up space for layout purposes.

So setting the visibility of layout to invisible just hides the layout, but does not free the consumed space. If you want to do that you have to set the visibility to gone.

[`Gone`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE) does what you want:

> This view is invisible, and it doesn't
>   take any space for layout purposes.

See also: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)

Answer (score 10):

Change `invisible` by `gone` that will do the trick.

> public static final int View.INVISIBLE
>
> This view is invisible, but it still
>   takes up space for layout purposes.
>   Use with setVisibility(int).

See [`View.GONE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE) and [`View.INVISIBLE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE)

Answer (score 6):

`invisible` will take up the same space as if it were `visible`.  Set the visibility to `gone` if you want it to take up no space.